# javascript indexOf does not work with numeric sequence

Tags: javascript, indexof

I'm trying to compare if a string, which I get from a JSON, starts with a certain number, for example if string 1.1.01.10.0001 starts with 1.1.01.10. I wrote this code to test this:

```
var result = JSON.parse(data);
for (x in result.group){
    var group = JSON.stringify(x.group);
    for (y in result.account){
        var account = JSON.stringify(y.account);
        console.log(group);
        console.log(account);
        if (account.indexOf(group) != -1){
            alert("ok");
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know where the error is, the console returns this here:

[image: img console]

In the first result it should return some number other than -1, how to solve this?

Comment: Can you post the JSON string value of `data`?

Comment: `indexOf` works properly see it here https://jsfiddle.net/2nmu8pfo/ . double check your code to make sure the value you are using is the correct one. For e.g if you check `"1.1.01.10.0001".indexOf("1.1.01.10.")` it will be true but the opposite wont.

Comment: when I put the direct value as indicated by @Elmer Dantas it works, when I pass the variable it does not work ..

Comment: I solved The problem was that when I took the variable string it came between "" and indexOf included the "" in the query and could not find anything right. To resolve, I put JSON.stringify (y.account) .replace (/ ["] / g, ''), removing" "the string and it worked.

Comment: as I imagined...the value you were using was not the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

For given JSON, this is working fine

```js
var data = {
  "group": [{
    "description": "xxxxx",
    "group": "1.1.01.10"
  }, {
    "description": "xxxxx",
    "group": "1.1.01.20"
  }],
  "account": [{
    "description": "xxxxx",
    "account": "1.1.01.10.001"
  }, {
    "description": "xxxxx",
    "account": "1.1.01.20.001"
  }, {
    "description": "xxxxx",
    "account": "1.1.01.20.002"
  }, {
    "description": "xxxxx",
    "account": "1.1.01.20.003"
  }]
}
data = JSON.stringify(data);
var result = JSON.parse(data);

var customFn = function(val) {
  for (var x = 0; x < result[val].length; x++) {
    var value = result[val][x];
    console.log(value[val]);
    if (value[val].indexOf('1.1.01.10.') != -1) {
      alert("ok value is " + value[val]);
    }
  }
}
customFn('group');
customFn('account');
```

Comment: I thought this was the problem, but it did not work.

Comment: can you share the value of data

Comment: Json is a very large file has more than 500 records ... but it looks like this:

{"group":[{"description":"xxxxx", "group":"1.1.01.10"},{"description":"xxxxx", "group":"1.1.01.20"}], "account":[{"description":"xxxxx", "account":"1.1.01.10.001"},{"description":"xxxxx", "account":"1.1.01.20.001"},{"description":"xxxxx", "account":"1.1.01.20.002"},{"description":"xxxxx", "account":"1.1.01.20.003"}]}